# written a function which returns department name where employee is working and using the function to print employees firstname and department name

Tags: plsql

i want to write a function which returns department name where employee is working and using the function to print employees firstname and department name. the error am getting is that "empno must be declared"
here i the code:

```
create or replace function empdnm (empno1 number) return varchar2 is 
 deptname varchar (30);
BEGIN   
 SELECT d.department_name
 INTO   deptname
 FROM   DEPARTMENTS d
 JOIN   EMPLOYEES e on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
 WHERE  e.EMPLOYEE_ID = empno;

return(deptname);
 exception
   WHEN no_data_found THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('no employee with no:'|| empno);
end;

BEGIN
   FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES) loop
    dbms_output.put_line( 'employee '|| r.FIRST_name  || ' is in department  || empdnm(r.empno) );
END loop;
end;
```

Comment: Is this as simple as having `r.empno` in the code but `empno1` as the parameter?

Comment: i changed empno1 to empno but i still get the same error that empno must be declared

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to write such function and call it then for all the employees?
Way more efficient way would be to merge those queries into one:

```
DECLARE
    -- I prefer using explicitly declared cursors rather than implicit cursors (like SELECT .. INTO ..)
    CURSOR c_emp_dept IS
    SELECT
        e.first_name
        ,d.department_name
    FROM
        departments d
        ,employees e
    WHERE
        d.department_id = e.department_id;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN c_emp_dept
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('Employee '||r.first_name||' is in department '||r.department_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

If for some reason you need to create a function (some school task):

```
-- As IN parameter name for functions or procedures I use 'p_' prefix not to mess up my variables later
-- and to easily find my parameter usage in the function body
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_emp_dept_name(p_employee_id IN EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    CURSOR c_emp_dept IS
    SELECT
        d.department_name
    FROM
        departments d
        ,employees e
    WHERE
        d.department_id = e.department_id
        AND e.employee_id = p_employee_id;

    ls_dept_name        DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_emp_dept;
    FETCH c_emp_dept INTO ls_dept_name;
    CLOSE c_emp_dept;

    -- Declared Cursor doesn't throw NO_DATA_FOUND exception
    IF ls_dept_name IS NULL THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('There is either no employee with id '||p_employee_id||' or the department assignment was created wrongly.');
    END IF;

    -- Returns department name if found, NULL if not found
    RETURN ls_dept_name;

END get_emp_dept_name;
/

DECLARE
    ls_dept_name        DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
    -- Here I fetch only the columns that you actually use.
    -- The EMPLOYEES table may contain some huge sized columns (e.g. CLOB) and fetching it without even using it
    -- would only result in occuppying the DB memory
    FOR r IN (SELECT e.employee_id, e.first_name FROM employees e)
    LOOP
        ls_dept_name := GET_EMP_DEPT_NAME(p_employee_id => r.employee_id);
        dbms_output.put_line('Employee '||r.first_name||' is in department '||ls_dept_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```